# write equivalent of SAS macro in R

Tags: r, sas, macros, migration

Apologies for the repetition, but I realise I wrote badly what I'm getting at, so here's my second attempt:

I have the following macro in SAS, and I'm trying to migrate it to R:

```
%macro recode_var(var=);
if &var in (1,2,3,4,5) then do;
    if &var = 1 then &var._r = 0;
    if &var = 2 then &var._r = 25;
    if &var = 3 then &var._r = 50;
    if &var = 4 then &var._r = 75;
    if &var = 5 then &var._r = 100;
end;
%mend;
```

This is called by the line

```
%recode_var(var=Q7_1);
```

This creates a new variable Q7_1_r with values based on the values of Q7_1. I have 100 variables to call the macro for (e.g. Q7_5, Q15_6, Q35_4). What is the best way to write an R equivalent?

The following is a reproducible example of what I tried:

```
    Q1_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    Q1_2 <- c(5,4,5,3,2)
    Q1_3 <- c(3,4,5,1,1)

    df <- data.frame(Q1_1,Q1_2,Q1_3)

    df

    testvar <- function(var){
    newfile <- mutate(df, var||_r = case_when(var == 1 ~ 0,
                                                var == 2 ~ 25,
                                                var == 3 ~ 50,
                                                var == 4 ~ 75,
                                                var == 5 ~ 100))
    }

    testing <- testvar(df$Q1_2)
    testing <- testvar(df$Q1_3)
    testing
```

This works to create a new variable called "var_r", which has values that are based on the value of the input variable. (e.g. for Q1_2, it gives var_r as 100, 75, 100, 50, 25, and Q1_3 yields 50, 75, 100, 0, 0). This new variable is an extra column to the data frame. There are two things I'm trying to do with this and am seeking advice on:

1. I would like the name of the output variable to be based on the name of the input variable - to take the name of the input variable and add "_r" to it E.g. instead of "var_r", if the input variable, var, was Q6_1, the new variable would be Q6_1_r. I would like this to apply to any input value of the input variable "var", and then run the line of code below (testing <- testvar(df$Q1_2)) to assign a value of "var" which would then become part of the name of the new variable.
2. I have over 100 variables for this block to apply to, so once I do it once e.g. for Q1_2, I would like to run it again and add another variable to the set, e.g. Q2_2.

Thus, the output at the end of the above would have six columns -

Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3, Q1_1_r, Q1_2_r, Q1_3_r

with appropriate entries based on the code. If I can do this for the reproducible example, then I can apply it to the 100 variables I have. I hope this is clearer now. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

One easy approach is something like this:

```
# amended dataset to cover additional needs:
Q1_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Q1_2 <- c(5,4,5,3,2)
Q1_3 <- c(7,6,5,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Q1_1,Q1_2,Q1_3)

library(tidyverse)

typeA <- c("Q1_1", "Q1_2")
typeB <- c("Q1_3")

df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(typeA), # Apply the function to each column whose name matches a string in object typeA
                ~ case_when(
                  . == 1 ~ 0,
                  . == 2 ~ 25,
                  . == 3 ~ 50,
                  . == 4 ~ 75,
                  . == 5 ~ 100),
                .names = "{.col}_r")) %>% # name of new column is the old name plus "_r" 
  mutate(across(all_of(typeB), # again but for typeB
                ~ case_when(
                  . == 1 ~ 0,
                  . == 2 ~ 12.5,
                  . == 3 ~ 25,
                  . == 4 ~ 37.5,
                  . == 5 ~ 50,
                  . == 6 ~ 62.5,
                  . == 7 ~ 75,
                  . == 8 ~ 87.5,
                  . == 9 ~ 100),
                .names = "{.col}_r"))
```

Output:

```
  Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q1_1_r Q1_2_r Q1_3_r
1    1    5    7      0    100   75.0
2    2    4    6     25     75   62.5
3    3    5    5     50    100   50.0
4    4    3    1     75     50    0.0
5    5    2    1    100     25    0.0
```

If you really want to make it a function that takes a variable you can, but if you can work out a select-statement that defines the columns (e.g. my `starts_with("Q")`, or vectors of suitable titles) then this is a simple way to do it.

Note - this may be overcomplicating things.  If the ratio is just as per your example and that's not just a simplified version, then you could just do something like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(typeA),
                ~ (.-1)*25,
                .names = "{.col}_r")) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(typeB), 
                ~ (.-1)*12.5,
                .names = "{.col}_r"))
```

edit: updated to allow different blocks of answer types

Comment: Thank you for your reply. While it's a good one to know, unfortunately it won't work in the current situation, as I have three blocks of code similar to the example above, but different (for example, one has seven options in case_when instead of 5.  The code that I have above would be used for Q7, but the other variations would be used for Q6 and Q8. I would need to make sure I apply the right block of code to the rights "Q", and there are over 100 variables that each require one of the three blocks of code.  Thus, I'd need to call the appropriate block for each different "Q". Ask if unclear

Comment: ok, is there any way to define which columns to apply each approach to other than just listing them?  If not then listing them is fine e.g. `across(c(Q6, Q8),...)` or use an external vector.

Comment: What I would have would be more like - Block A would apply to (for example) Q6, Q51, Q24, Block B would apply to Q7, Q25, Q43, Block C would apply to Q8, Q9, Q10, Q45 etc.  I think there would be a list of variables for which each Block of code would apply to

Comment: I've updated my answer - hopefully it's now suitable to adapt to your needs.

Comment: So, would this mean, if I were to use the example above, if, type A applied to Q1_1 to Q1_3, type B to Q16_1 to Q16_7 and type C to Q35_1 to Q35_5, then the code would be :    df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3),
                ~ (.-1)*25,
                df.names = "{df.col}_r")) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(Q16_1, Q16_2, Q16_3, Q16_4, Q16_5, Q16_6, Q16_7), 
                ~ (.-1)*12.5,
                df.names = "{df.col}_r")) %>%
mutate(across(all_of(Q35_1, Q35_2, Q35_3, Q35_4, Q35_5), 
                ~ (.1)*25,
                df.names = "{df.col}_r")) %>%?

Comment: yes, and to make it even easier, if the rows are sequential you can instead just use the first and last column names separated by a colon to show a range e.g. `across(Q16_1:Q16_7)`

Comment: Thank you for the above. I tried and came up with an error message of an unexpected symbol. The next comment is what I typed - forgive me if it appears untidy and please let me know how to write it in the tidy format you have used above as I'm not sure how. The error message was - Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                ~ (.7)*100
                .names"

Comment: df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(df$Q6_1, df$Q6_2, df$Q6_3, df$Q6_4,df$Q6_5, df$Q6_6),
                ~ (.1)*0,
                ~ (.2)*16.67,
                ~ (.3)*33.33,
                ~ (.4)*50,
                ~ (.5)*66.67,
                ~ (.6)*83.33,
                ~ (.7)*100
                .names == "{.col}_r")) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(df$Q8_1, df$Q8_2, df$Q8_3, df$Q8_4), 
                ~ (.1)*0,
                ~ (.2)*25,
                ~ (.3)*50,
                ~ (.4)*75,
                ~ (.5)*100
                .names == "{.col}_r"))

Comment: you've got `(.1)` `(.2)` etc instead of `(.-1)`.  I think you've misunderstood.  the `.` stands for "the value in each row of the column" so `(.-1)*25` means "the value, minus one, then times twenty five" so `1` becomes `(1-1)*25` = `0*25` = `0`.   Similarly, `2` becomes `(2-1)*25` = `1*25` = `25` and so on.